# Why does `ps -e` display information about the current user's processes?

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina

I'm currently on macOS Catalina:

```
nlykkei:~/projects$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2
BuildVersion:   19C57
```

I wonder why the `-e` (identical to `-A`) option of `ps` displays information about my current user's processes, when only the `-a` option mentions:

> Display information about other users' processes **as well as your own**.

```
 -A      Display information about other users' processes, including those without controlling terminals.

 -a      Display information about other users' processes as well as your own.  This will skip any processes which do not have a controlling terminal, unless the -x option is also specified.

...

 -e      Identical to -A.
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is just sloppy phrasing in the `man` page; both `-A` and `-a` list all users' processes (other users *as well as your own*).

Answer (score 1):

The “e” or `-e` option was originally for **e**very process.  It was deprecated with the `-A` for **A**ll processes.  It remains as a carry over for POSIX compliance with historical versions.

The difference between `-a` and `-A` is

- `-a` only shows other *users* processes with a controlling terminal.
- `-A` shows all process even if they are not attached to a terminal, like a daemon

According to the man page,

> The ps utility supports the Version 3 of the Single UNIX Specification (``SUSv3'') standard.

macOS is one of the few *certified* POSIX compliant Unix operating systems that conform to the [Single Unix Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Currently_registered_UNIX_systems) as such, all utilities included must also be POSIX compliant.

Additionally, in the man page, there is a section titled **Legacy Description** (IMO, bad wording) where it details the difference between POSIX `ps` and Legacy `ps`

> In legacy mode, ps functions as described above, with the following differences:
>
> -e      Display the environment as well. Same as -E.

Comment: thanks. Since your descriptions of `-a` and `-A` doesn’t match the descriptions of `man ps`, I guess what you are saying is that the man page is wrong? Are your descriptions of above options from the official POSIX specification? Also by “historical versions” you mean POSIX?

Comment: Mine came from the actual man page on macOS.  Just saw my mistake.  -a is for all other users processes.  -A includes your